# Trouble with installing Ubuntu on a virtual machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Whenever I click on any element in the menu while installing Ubuntu, the only thing that appears is this black screen with flashing underline, and nothing else happens. Can someone please help me with this issue? Thanks in advance
Lubuntu 18.04 Desktop
VirtualBox 5.2.22

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dKo5.png)

Comment: Please state which version, distribution of Ubuntu you are trying to install. Desktop? Server? 19.10 or older?

Comment: Also what version of Virtualbox?  Please edit the Question using the edit button to the left of your avatar.

Comment: I've tried different versions and distributions of Ubuntu with no result, but this specific one is Lubuntu

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 Desktop VirtualBox 5.2.22

Comment: Have you tried updating VirtualBox? 5.2.22 was release ~1 year ago. The recommended major version is now 6.x.

Comment: Updated , no result